# Как передать данные из activity в sliding tab fragment

Tags: android, tab

У меня есть некая строковая переменная, которую я хочу передать в tab fragment

Пробовал через bundle - ругается на NullPointerException, однако в эту активити я данную переменную получил из другого activity, так что там полюбому не null.

Здесь код OnCreate моего  Activity

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_extended);
    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity
    tab1 = new Tab1();
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);



    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String href = extras.getString("href");
        link=href;
        String name = extras.getString("name");
        label=name; }
    ExtendedActivity.this.setTitle(label);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("link", link);
    tab1.setArguments(bundle);
```

Собственно тут и написано через bundle

 А тут код фрагмента Tab1:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
String Link="";
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public Tab1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentSettings.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static Tab1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    Tab1 fragment = new Tab1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

    Link = getArguments().getString("link");
    this.getActivity().setTitle(Link);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}




public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

Помогите разобраться, что же мне тут сделать?

Правка1:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_extended);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        link = extras.getString("href");
        label = extras.getString("name");
    }

    tab1 = Tab1.newInstance(link, null);

    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity
  //  tab1 = new Tab1();
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);



    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    ExtendedActivity.this.setTitle(label);
}
```

а это Tab1:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "link";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public Tab1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentSettings.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static Tab1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    Tab1 fragment = new Tab1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }


  this.getActivity().setTitle(mParam1);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуй сделать следующее:

1) вытаскивай `extras` после строки `setContentView(R.layout.activity_extended);`

2) вынеси переменные `String href` и `String name` из тела условия

3) создавай экземпляр класса `Tab1` через фабричный метод `Tab1.newInstance()`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_extended);
    String href;
    String name;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        link = href = intent.getString("href");
        label = name = intent.getString("name");
    }
    tab1 = Tab1.newInstance(link, null);
    ...
}
```

Еще, я бы не советовал давать имена переменным начинающиеся с заглавной буквы (`String Link="";`)

ну, и небольшие правки в классе `Tab1`

```
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "link";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach (Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.getActivity().setTitle(mParam1);
}
```

Comment: Ура, благодаря вашему комментарию, ошибка nullPointerException перестала вылезать, однако заголовок Tab1 теперь пуст. Может я что то проглядел, обновлю топик с принятыми изменениями

Comment: А в классе `Tab1` 1) изменил значение константы `ARG_PARAM1`? 2) передали в метод `setTitle` `mParam1`?

Comment: обновил топик, вроде все поменял

Comment: попробуй вместо `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();` написать `Intent intent = getIntent();` и брать строку прямо из интента (если при старте активити закидываешь строки в сам интент)

Comment: ну и не помешает в лог записывать значение строки на каждом шаге, чтоб сузить круг поиска

Comment: А смысл? строки в Extended Activity я получаю исправно, если     ExtendedActivity.this.setTitle(label); работает корректно

Comment: `this.getActivity().setTitle(mParam1);` перенеси в `onCreateView`

Comment: ошибка unreachable statement, да и если вместо mParam1 я ставлю "123" то все гуд, title ставится

Comment: `this.getActivity().setTitle(mParam1);` стоит перед `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);`? Покажи код.

Comment: ахахаххахах не стоит, вот блин. извини за дезу) исправил, но проблема осталась

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37388/discussion-between-ivan-dembicki-and-alex).

Answer (score 2):

у вас есть прямая ссылка на ваш фрагмент

```
tab1 = new Tab1();
```

Создайте во фрагменте метод

```
public void setData(String data) {
    //делайте все, что нужно с этими данными
}
```

И  нужном месте в `Activity` вызывайте

```
tab1.setData("строка, которую нужно передать");
```

Comment: Блин, все равно NullPointerException, в тех строках где передаю строку и делаю действия со строкой во фрагменте

Comment: @Alex в какой строке `Exception`?

Answer (score 1):

Делайте

```
tab1 = Tab1.newInstance(data);
```

`NullPointerException` вылетает, так как в `onCreateView` вы пытаетесь получать аргументы, а если создали фрагмент через `new Tab1`, они будут `null`.